# Maven Sample Android App deploy fails constantly after one successful run

Tags: android, maven, adb

I downloaded the examples from simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin and did a `mvn clean package android:deploy` on the helloflashlight example.
After setting adbConnectionTimeout to 15000 everything went fine for one run. I deployed the app sucessfully - the app started on my device and I was able to push the color buttons.

After that I ran `mvn android:undeploy` to clean the device. Now I am not able to deploy this test app again. Maven says FAILURE "E/Device: Error during Sync: Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen" Which means an open connection was closed by remote host(?).

I googled and found out that the problem may be 2 processes of adb.exe starting during deploy. So I entered `adb kill-server` and shut the adb down. 
Still on each deploy 2 adb.exe are starting, one is shutting down immediatly, the other stays open. Searching for adb.exe at my computer only finds one adb.exe.

Does anybody have some hints for me?

My system setup:

I installed Eclipse with current ADT (Android Deploment Tools).
I used the Android SDK Manager to download and install android sdk and tools into C:\users\me\android-sdk. I added a samsung device to the device list which is displayed when I enter `adb devices`

After that I configured Maven for android - setting `ANDROID_HOME` and added `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools` to my PATH.

I am working with Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: If you need two different ADB connections, try using different ports for each ADB instance. That's probably why the second one is finishing immediately.

Comment: try to kill all adb in task manager process after killing all those restart an adb it will work.

Comment: @MaheshGiri I stopped/killed successfully with "adb kill-server" and also via taskmanager - I also started adb via "adb start-server" or run maven without an adb started - it doesn't seem to matter: in every constellation I always get the same error

Comment: @Shark I don't need two adb - I think it may be my problem, but I don't know how to prevent maven from starting an adb instance during android:deploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be a problem with the device. I switch to another device of same type... no problems any more.

Comment: Wasn't the device, using another usb-cable did the job too.